# Get embedded url of pbix power bi report that has paginated rdl report inside it

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, row-level-security, powerbi-paginated-reports

When I get the embedded url of pbix report that has the paginated rdl report in it and load it in an iframe the pbix report is visible but the paginated report is not show. The paginated report has some errors is the error seen in the UI.

But,when I open it from the power bi desktop the pbix report with paginated report is shown